# When open a lot of page and close while its loading, my server go down

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, php

Our web site : http://netmoda.com,

lets open a few combine and close while page loading and my server will down.Why that can be like that ?

My server stack : Ubuntu server 2 cluster, nginx, php5-fpm, phalcon and mysql.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it, but still works. Have you tried finding bugs in your webpage?

Comment: I'd but im thinking that it can be cuz of nginx or php-fpm or maybe cloudflare ?